# What is the name of this font in latex?

Tags: fonts

I would like to learn this type of fonts in latex. I have tried all the math fonts but it does not seem to be ana appropriate one. So my question is:what  the name of this font in latex?
[image]

### Answer of Heiko Oberdiek

The question is already closed, thus I have to use the question for the answer; images cannot be put in comments.

Comparison of the image in the question

> [image: question]

and the typewriter font of Computer Modern (or EC or Latin Modern):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{age=25 AND name=`Bob'.}
\end{document}
```

> [image: age25-cm]

Together with the original in black and the `\texttt` variant in red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\raise.8pt\rlap{\includegraphics[width=50mm,trim=0 0 -.7pt 0]{age25.png}}%
\textcolor{red}{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{age25-cm.pdf}}%

\end{document}
```

> [image: comparison]

The thickness is quite correct.

However the space between the `'` and `.` is smaller.
Next idea: the `.` is not set in a fixed-width font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{age=25 AND name=`Bob'}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: rm-dot]

Comparison with this variant yields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
  \leavevmode
  \raise1pt\rlap{\includegraphics[width=50mm,trim=-.25pt 0 -1.25pt 0]{age25.png}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{t-crop.pdf}}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Final comparison]

**Result:** `` \texttt{age=25 AND name=`Bob'}. `` (`cmtt` or `lmtt`)

Comment: `\texttt{<Your text>}`

Comment: `tiniestfont` ever, from that very, very, very, very tiny screen shot `;-)` ... Seriously, it looks like typewriter font, created with `\texttt{...}`

Comment: It doesn't seem so...It is more bold and small than texttt

Answer (score 2):

Although the screenshot provides a font more bold, this might be an issue of the displaying program or the display itself, I am rather sure, that is `\texttt{}`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\tiny%
\texttt{age=25 AND name=`Bob'}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We got *.It is more bold and small than texttt* as a comment

Comment: @percusse: I do not claim that my trial of solution and the OP's screenshot are identical, but is rather near at the edge `;-)`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Yes, I noticed it too, and changed `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}%% a good alternative
\begin{document}
\texttt{age=25 and name=`Bob'}
\end{document}
```